# Calculation of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Calculate the series $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}$$

I tried the root test but couldn't figure out, any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:$$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n^{2}+n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$$

Note that the root test is a test for convergence not a way to calculate the value of the series.

Comment: Both are divergents, how I calculate their valor? Partial sum?

Comment: Use partial sums and notice that the series is telescoping.

Comment: May I use integration for the calculus?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use integration to evaluate the sum but there may be a way.

Comment: @arthurg It's best to use telescoping as user# stated, and pair off the terms that cancel.

Comment: @Chinny84 Got it, thank you and everybody!

Comment: On behalf of Math Stack Exchange. You're welcome.

Comment: Nicely put @user71352 :)

Comment: @Chinny84 Thank you. :)